# Result set error if no records are returned by db - codiegniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Message: Trying to get property of non-object**

When records are found in the db there are no errors, but the above error is given when no result is returned by the query.

How to solve it?

```
public function filessearch($id,$type){

$this->db->from('files');
$this->db->like('FTitle',$id);
$this->db->where('FBlock','UnBlock');
$this->db->where('FFullType',$type);
$this->db->limit(50);
$this->db->order_by('FID','DESC');
$this->db->group_by('FTitle');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: thanks bro solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is giving you that error ain't in the code you showed us, but I can identify and guess the issue.

Somewhere in your code you do something like this:

```
$fileResults = $this->your_model->filessearch($someId, $someType);

echo $fileResults[0]->some_column;
```

And what happens is that if no result is returned from database the index zero **[0]** doesn't exists.
Validate first if the array is not empty.

```
if(count($fileResults) > 0)
   echo $fileResults[0]->some_column;
```